# Selenium Webdriver issue with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
print("Sample test initiated")
#driver selection
driver = webdriver.chrome(r"/Users/ananyarai/Downloads/chromedriver.exe")
```

It causes the following error:

```
"/Users/ananyarai/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/bin/python "/Users/ananyarai/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/Demo /Sample 2.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ananyarai/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/Demo /Sample 2.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.chrome(r"/Users/ananyarai/Downloads/chromedriver.exe")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"
Sample test initiated
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. It is good to show us your code and your error message, but you also need to a) try to *read and understand* the error message; b) try to fix the problem yourself (see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592); c) explain why that failed; d) *ask a question*.

Comment: Also: When you run into problems trying to do even basic things with a third-party library, you should first think of reading the documentation. Usually it will have examples of common use. You can also try using a search engine: [for example](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=selenium+webdriver.chrome+example).

Answer (score 0):

I think you misspelled this part here `driver = webdriver.chrome(r"/Users/ananyarai/Downloads/chromedriver.exe")`

Using something like `driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\path to \\chromedriver.exe')`gets the desired result.